# Halo LED can (H455 series) troubleshooting

Tags: electrical, lighting, led

A set of five Halo EL405827 LED lights mounted in H455ICAT120D cans was installed in our kitchen about ten years ago.

Recently one light went out.  When that EL405827 is put in a different can, it works.  When one of the other EL405827s is put in the "dead" H455ICAT120D can, it does not light up.

(All five EL405827 LED lights work.  One H455ICAT120D can appears not to.)

With the light switch on, there is about 4 VAC at the output pins of both working and "dead" H455ICAT120Ds.  (I can't tell the difference between them with the voltmeter.)

What could be the problem with the "dead" H455ICAT120D and how can it be fixed?
What is inside a H455ICAT120D anyway?  Is it just a transformer?

All troubleshooting, repair or replacement suggestions welcome!

Comment: At a minimum, a picture of the can in question (and, possibly of a working one) would be helpful. Is there any indication of scorching or burn marks anywhere on the can? All in all, it may be easier (and possibly more cost effective) to simply replace the can.

Comment: Replace the can if you can do that.  You also might be able to buy a new can, pull out the driver (electronics) module, and use it to replace the one in the existing can.

Comment: Note that the electronics that are part of a LED bulb (or bulb system) is usually the weak link in so far as the longevity of an LED.  They dissipate a fair amount of heat which has to be dissipated to the environment, which is why you don't want to use a normal LED bulb in an enclosed fixture.  Even with proper heat dissipation, some components tend to wear out especially electrolytic capacitors which leads to the failure.

Comment: Thank you for your comments.  Pictures of Halo EL405827 LED lights and H455ICAT120D cans are readily available via Google.  There are no scorch or burn marks.  The H455ICAT120D is obsolete and therefore non-trivial to replace.  There is nothing wrong with the EL405827 LED bulb system as noted in the original post.  Checking for bad components in the driver might be worthwhile, but why would its output so closely approximate that of a working driver if there was a bad component?  Thanks for taking the time to consider the question.

Answer (score 2):

Most LED lights for lighting are supplied DC power in *constant-current* mode.  Even as conditions change, an LED is given - say - 350mA of current (at whatever voltage that happens to occur at, within reason).   Obviously AC power doesn't provide DC constant-current, so there's a <del>ballast</del> *LED Driver* in between AC power and the LED *proper*.

Normally the driver is soldered onto the same board as the LED emitters. These downlights are fairly unique in that the driver is in the can -- and they have a proprietary connector for LED emitter heads, which are constant-current DC *at a specific current*).

(which is why your AC setting showed no voltage).

A reason to bother with exchangeable LED emitter heads is to allow varying *color temperature*, and also ease of assembly.

Contact Halo to see if the driver can be purchased separately.  However there is nothing mystical about drivers; match the spec and another one should do.  The important thing (sorry if I'm dumbing this down), is **the current must match exactly** and the voltage *range* needs to be appropriate for the bulb.

The voltage of the bulb must be tested in-circuit, either powered from its driver or a bench supply set to that same current. The open-circuit voltage of a disconnected driver is meaningless.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to consider the question.  I appreciate the effort, but this response isn't useful enough for me to mark it as an answer.

Comment: @Riccati could you be more explicit in the way that "this response isn't useful enough for me to mark it as an answer"? It provided an indication of what is in the can (one of your questions) and a suggestion for where/how to get a replacement (your other question). What additional details would you like, as this seems perfectly reasonable to me?

Comment: @FreeMan  That the can contains a driver is obvious.  If there were some details of how the driver works, what components of it fail most often, why it could be faulty yet still produce the same AC voltage as the working drivers, how to fix it, etc, that might be useful.  Similarly, "contact the manufacturer" is the first thing I did, along with web research, perusing wikis, checking YouTube, and all the usual, basic troubleshooting tricks.  Sometimes people have very detailed knowledge to share if they've had the same problem.  That hasn't happened in this case.

Comment: @riccati good point and I'll improve.  That said, re: "is obvious", tailoring answers to your skill level is impossible as we don't know it, and also  these Q&A get seen by many other people (we actually get stats on that).  So please expect enough dumb-down to bring *the average* person up to speed.

Comment: Fair enough, @Riccati. I'm a reasonably competent DIYer, but I wouldn't attempt to repair the driver/transformer, I'd simply replace and the easiest/most cost-effective way might just be to replace the whole can. You obviously have greater electronics skills than I and that would be a reasonable thing for you to consider, but it wasn't obvious from your post. Thanks for clarifying what you're after.